# Deployng Class Mediator and Artifact by CAR archive

Tags: deployment, wso2, osgi, mediator, wso2-esb

i'm using WSO2 Developer Studio 3.5.
I have developed a series of configuration artifacts inside a synapse-config project.

Then i developed my  own custom class mediator.

Eventually i created a Composite Application Project. Inside its pom, i selected the config project and the class mediator.

Using mvn clean install command i created the CAR archive.

I entered the management console and i added the car file through the carbon app section. Looking at the my wso2 esb 4.8.1 log of  i saw some exceptions:

```
[2015-05-23 23:52:58,900] ERROR - CappAxis2Deployer Error while deploying carbon application C:\CodeHome\WSO2ES~1.1\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\carbonapps\Diogene-WSO2CAR_1.0.0.car
org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: Error while backing up the artifact: DynamicEndpointConfigurationTask-1.0.0.xml
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.handleSynapseArtifactDeploymentError(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:473)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.backupFile(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:517)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:197)
    at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:251)
    at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:79)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file 'C:\CodeHome\WSO2ES~1.1\bin\..\repository\carbonapps\work\1432417976326Diogene-WSO2CAR_1.0.0.car\DynamicEndpointConfigurationTask_1.0.0\DynamicEndpointConfigurationTask-1.0.0.xml' after copy to 'C:\CodeHome\wso2esb-4.8.1\repository\carbonapps\work\1432417976326Diogene-WSO2CAR_1.0.0.car\DynamicEndpointConfigurationTask_1.0.0\DynamicEndpointConfigurationTask-1.0.0.xml.back'
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.java:2109)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.backupFile(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:515)
    ... 22 more
```

indeed it seems the class mediator was not loaded. I tried different times but i got always the same result.
This result is confirmed by clicking the load class button on the design view of my proxy when i try to add my class mediator: "Class not found in the path".
 Is the manual copy into components/lib folder the only way to add a custom class mediator to my wso2 esb?

Comment: The exception above is a failed attempt of file removal. Have you tried to remove it manually? I'd clean up the whole "work" directory in fact

Answer (score 0):

A mediation class should be packaged in a jar-file and put in on the server in `<installdir>/repository/components/lib`.

Also, your error indicates a faulty deployment of the car-file. Did you undeploy from the admin console first, or a redeploy? Or a deploy from Developer Studio?

Comment: The error occurs on the first deploy. I wrote a multimodule maven project.. the modules of which are the class mediator, the synapse config project and finally the car project. This way the class mediator is built and installed in local repo as jar file. The final result is a car file containing the xml artifacts and jar file. I tried to intall it through the management console logged in as admin. My target is to aim a car file by which installing both config artifact and class mediator jar.

Comment: You need to add the jar file to the server manually, deploying it using the car file does not work.

Comment: But afak wso2 esb is osgi, so isn't possible to install a mediator as a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

create a mediator project and inside that write ur own custom class. the create the archive from the pom.xml of ur mediator project and place it inside
/repository/components/lib

Next in ur CAR project change the POM by adding dependency of ur mediator project and then finally create the car file.